# Why does US law look at biological age rather than mental age?

Tags: united-states

In many cases, it can be hard to tell what a person's [mental age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_age) is, especially as one's mental capacity changes much less rapidly as one gets older. But sometimes one's mental age can be very obvious. Some people have a [mental disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_disability) in which mentally they are much more immature than they are physically.

There was a case I saw on the news recently of two women who had this condition and were mentally the age of teenagers. They would take a private bus to their psychiatrist, provided by the medical institution. Their bus driver decided to take advantage of them and sexually assaulted them. However, as both parties were over the age of 18, the women's families were unable to prosecute. (I'm probably forgetting a few details, but that was the gist of it.)

Why should this be? If the women's physical age corresponded to their mental age, this would be a criminal activity. Why should the fact that physically they are older be a mitigating circumstance?

I'm asking in general, not in respect to this case in particular. I bring this up as an example to illustrate the concept.

Comment: Can you reference the specific case?  Most places have laws where having some form of mental developmental impairment makes it not possible to give consent. For laws regarding sexual crimes, it is a combination of biological age, mental age and mental condition/capacity at the time. I feel like the premise is flawed, and those families, if their adult-aged children had a reduced capacity, would have been able to prosecute.  But I'm also assuming USA.

Comment: I think biologic age is considered in the vast majority of cases in virtually all countries for practical reasons. It's a single number, so it can be easily compared to a threshold. Mental age is way less clear and harder to use. You have to map it to a single dimension and set some clear thresholds which is not easy..

Comment: This question is based on a faulty premise in that nearly any case involving any sort of mental deficiency will take into consideration aspects outside of the physical ages. No idea if it's related to your example case, but there are also issues with what is deemed abuse with adults with mental disabilities (sometimes truly consenting adults with mental disabilities are seen as victims...which is a whole other debate...)

Answer (score 10):

You pretty much answered your own question.

> In many cases, it can be hard to tell what a person's mental age is,
>   especially as one's mental capacity changes much less rapidly as one
>   gets older.

Even in clearer case, determining precisely what someone's mental age is a matter upon which reasonable people and even reasonable experts can disagree. Also, the concept of "mental age" tends to break down in the case of elderly people who have declining mental function.

But, chronological age (it really has nothing to do with being organic as opposed to inorganic), can be determined as a trivial matter from a single official public document (such as a birth certificate) that is not reasonably subject to question or dispute.

Also, the law usually is focused on protecting the young in the kinds of circumstances you reference, and the percentage of people who have a mental age materially younger than their chronological age is quite small as a percentage of the total population.

Usually, it is easier to have a bright line set of rules based upon chronological age, and then to have a parallel set of rules designed to protect people who are developmentally disabled.

For example, in Colorado, there is a statute codified at Colorado Revised Statutes §§ 18-6.5-101 to 18-6.5-107 that addresses "Wrongs to At-risk Adults", which provides protections similar to age based protections for a group of people who include people who have a mental age less than their chronological age.

Comment: Also, mental age and mental capacity are two very different things.

Comment: @jamesqf Mental age and mental capacity may be different things, but they aren't unrelated. Mental age is a shorthand way of describing one particular pattern of mental capacity evaluations. It can be useful when the whole suite of the salient mental capacities correspond to the mental capacity of a person of a certain age. It is less useful when a person's mental capacities do not line up with the mental capacities of an average person at any age (e.g. if someone has hallucinations but is solid in reasoning and memory).

Comment: Perhaps we are talking about different things when we say "mental age".  (And the couple of linked paragraphs don't help much.)  But for an example, I have a mental capacity sufficient to get graduate degrees and have a successful career in a technically-demanding field, yet my friends pretty much agree that my mental age is about 12 at most.

Comment: @jamesqf Ha ha!

Answer (score 0):

Rape is fundamentally sexual contact without consent. Physical age is one of the standards by which consent is judged, so if a person is under 16 [in Washington](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.44.079), they are deemed to have limited ability to consent to sex (the rules are kind of arcane). [A person under 12](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.44.073) is deemed to be absolutely incapable of consenting (except with the person they are married to).

So likewise there are other situations where consent is deemed to be lacking, [for example](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.44.050)

> (b) When the victim is incapable of consent by reason of being
>   physically helpless or mentally incapacitated;
>
> (c) When the victim is a person with a developmental disability and
>   the perpetrator is a person who is not married to the victim and who:
>
> (i) Has supervisory authority over the victim; or
>
> (ii) Was providing transportation, within the course of his or her
>   employment, to the victim at the time of the offense;

A family does not prosecute, the state does, so one would have to know more details of the event to determine exactly why there was no prosecution. Normally, there would be.

The reason why mental age is not part of the calculation is that there is too much scientific leeway in making that determination. Since the underlying point is that sexual contact (which is inherently "offensive" in common law jargon) requires consent and certain people are incapable of consent, introducing "mental age" would be at odds with the real point of age specifications in rape laws.

Comment: `except with the person they are married to` - That's a pretty odd caveat in that law.  Is it legal to get married below age 12 in Washington?  **Edit:** Nevermind.  [Wikipedia to the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_marriage_in_the_United_States)

Comment: A did issue is **proving** that the claimed rapist know consent was not given.    As often some people will answer yes to any question to keep everyone happy, and unless it can be proved the rapid know this about the given person.